# Using SVG in an XSL stylesheet

Tags: xslt, svg, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP to generate PDF's.  My data is in a XML file and I use a XSL stylesheet to render it.  I am having trouble using SVG in my stylesheet.  I have create an SVG which is

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="400" height="400" id="svg2">
<path d="M200,200  L390,200  A190,190 0 0,1 200,390  z"  fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-linejoin="round" />
<path d="M200,200  L200,390  A190,190 0 0,1 10,200  z"  fill="orange" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-linejoin="round" />
<path d="M200,200  L10,200  A190,190 0 0,1 200,10  z"  fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-linejoin="round" />
<path d="M200,200  L200,10  A190,190 0 0,1 390,200  z"  fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

But how do I put it in the stylesheet.  I have tried putting it in an `<fo:instream-foreign-object>` like

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <svg:svg width="400" height="400">
    <svg:path d="M200,200  L390,200  A190,190 0 0,1 200,390  z"  fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-linejoin="round" />
...
    </svg:svg>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

But this doesn't work.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `<fo:instream-foreign-object>` should work, that's how they do it in one of their samples: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/dev/fo/embedding.fo (use view source). Please specify "doesn't work", that's too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its turns out I was doing it all wrong.  The correct way to do it is rather than doing

```
<svg:path stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-linejoin="round" />
```

You need to draw the path like this

```
<svg:path stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-linejoin="round">
    <xsl:attribute name="fill">red</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="d">M200,200  L390,200  A190,190 0 0,1 200,390  z</xsl:attribute>
</svg:path>
```

Answer (score 0):

He's my example of SVG inside FOP as a letter size background (with text 'background region'):

```
  <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute"
        top="0in" left="0in" width="8.5in" height="11in"
        content-height="scale-to-fit"  content-width="scale-to-fit" 
        scaling="non-uniform"
        background-position="center"  background-repeat="no-repeat"
        background-image="url(your_xml_file.svg)">
    <fo:block>background region
    </fo:block>
  </fo:block-container>
```